# Conditional Handler within Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible, handler

we use a users module that restarts sshd on a handler, however this is only valid if the server is Ubuntu 16.

I am trying to over ride it like so:

```
- name: Set SSH/SSHD service
  include_vars:
    ssh_service: "sshd"
  when: ( ansible_distribution_version == "16.04" ) and ( ansible_distribution == "Ubuntu" )

- name: Set SSH/SSHD service
  include_vars:
    ssh_service: "ssh"
  when: ( ansible_distribution_version == "14.04" ) and ( ansible_distribution == "Ubuntu" )
```

However this is returning an error regarding debug:

```
fatal: [172.48.0.146]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ssh_service is not a valid option in debug"}
```

The handler is as follows:

```
- name: restart_sshd
  service: name="{{ ssh_service }}"
           state=restarted
```

Is there a tidy way to do this? I don't want to have to specify this via groupvars.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per:

https://fossies.org/linux/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/action/include_vars.py

I am not using include_vars by design, it expects a file.

I can use `set_fact` instead:

```
- name: Set SSH/SSHD service
  set_fact:
    ssh_service: "sshd"
  when: ( ansible_distribution_version == "16.04" ) and ( ansible_distribution == "Ubuntu" )
```